# Servlet Dispatcher throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a simple Spring web flow application created. When the application starts, I get the following error on my Tomcat server:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:48)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:180)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:282)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:241)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:219)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
```

I am using Spring 2.5.6 , Spring web flow 2.0.8 with Tomcat 6.0.20...

Any idea why the `WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE` field is not available? How do I resolve this error?

Comment: do you have all the required jars?

Comment: Yes.. i have all the jars - spring, mvc & spring web flow jars... I actually modified a spring MVC application to Spring web flow application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've still got the same problem with your Spring JAR versions as you did in [Spring Web flow configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231031/spring-web-flow-configuration-error/2236402#2236402)

`RequestContext.WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE` wasn't present in Spring 2.0, only in 2.5.6 and later.

Comment: Exactly.. i am using Spring 2.5.6 and web flow 2.0.8.. i don't understand why this error comes up!!!?

Comment: Because somewhere in your app you have a copy of Spring 2.0, and that's being loaded first.